# Grub unable to access TFTP server to load grub config

Tags: boot, networking, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I am attempting to pxeboot and install Ubuntu 20.04 on my target computer configured to use UEFI.

My build server is a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. I am using dnsmasq as the dhcp/dns/tftp server for my build network.

When I attempt to pxeboot the target computer, it gets a DHCP address, downloads BOOTX64.EFI, then downloads grubx64.efi, both from the TFTP server.

However, I'm then left at a grub prompt. In the grub CLI, $prefix is set to `(tftp.192.168.105.1)/EFI/ubuntu`. This appears to be the correct address for the build server. However, I can not do an `ls $prefix` command because it tells me `error: disk 'tftp.192.168.105.1' not found.`

In addition, /var/log/syslog on the boot server reports that BOOTX64.EFI and grubx64.efi have been downloaded, but does not record any errors when I attempt to do an `ls $prefix`.

I'm not clear why this isn't working (since the target computer can clearly access files on the TFTP server). Can anyone suggest something to look at or another approach to take?

Answer (score 0):

You have a misspelling.

The address should read `(tftp,192.168.105.1)` with a coma not a point.